# Given that $|\vec u| = 8$ and $|\vec v| = 10$ and the angle between them is $60^\circ $ determine $|5 \vec u + 2 \vec v|$

Tags: vectors

I tried to use the cosine law but I got the wrong answer. I got $36.331$. The correct answer is supposed to be $52.915$.

Is there a mistake here? $$|5 \vec u + 2 \vec v|^2 = 5(8)^2 +2(10)^2 -2(40)(20)\cos(120^\circ)$$

Comment: It should be $|a \ \vec {u} + b \ \vec {v}|^2 = a^2|u|^2 + b^2|v|^2 + 2 ab |u| |v| \cos \theta$

Comment: @Math Lover, Why it is plus 2ab|u||v|cosθ instead of minus? And why is a and b squared? I still cannot get the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: because this is angle between vectors $\vec u \cdot \vec v = |u| |v| \cos\theta$. To the second part, how do you expand $(ax+by)^2 \ $? You may have made an error in calculation. Pls check.

Comment: @MathLover, I see what you mean now. I attempted this way but I got 60

Comment: you are still making a mistake somewhere, $\sqrt{40^2 + 20^2 + 40 \cdot 20} \ne 60$

Comment: I don't understand what this $120^o$ represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometric method: Refer to the figure:

[image]

Note:
$$S_{\Delta AFO}=\frac12\cdot AO\cdot FO\cdot \sin 60^\circ=\frac12\cdot 20\cdot 16\cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{2}=80\sqrt3$$
From the triangle $AFO$
$$AD=\frac{2S_{\Delta AFO}}{FO}=\frac{2\cdot 80\sqrt3}{16}=10\sqrt3=BE$$
From the triangle $ADO$:
$$DO=\sqrt{AO^2-AD^2}=\sqrt{20^2-(10\sqrt3)^2}=10=CE$$
Finally, from the triangle $BEO$:
$$|5\vec{u}+2\vec{v}|=BO=\sqrt{EO^2+BE^2}=\sqrt{50^2+(10\sqrt3)^2}=\sqrt{2800}\approx 52.915.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. We compute $|5\vec{u}+2\vec{v}|^2$ using the dot product:

$$
|5\vec{u}+2\vec{v}|^2 = (5\vec{u}+2\vec{v})\cdot(5\vec{u}+2\vec{v})
=
25\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}+20\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+4\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}
=25|\vec{u}|^2 + 20|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos\theta + 4|\vec{v}|^2
$$

so $|5\vec{u}+2\vec{v}|^2 = 1600+1600\cos\theta+400=2800$ (since $\cos 60^\circ=\frac{1}{2}$)

Therefore, $|5\vec{u}+2\vec{v}|=\sqrt{2800}=20\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: In the expansion, you must have $20\vec{u}\vec{v}$, hence the final answer will be $\sqrt{2800}$ as expected.